# Removing the base "Author" or changing it to something else. is it possible?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, author

Is it possible to remove the AUTHOR base?

Is it possible change it to postedBy so that the urls is site.com/postedBy/joe

And finally, is it possible to remove a custom taxonomy base from the url so that  a url like site.com/people/joe can become site.com/joe

Comment: take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Comment: That's beyond me at this time Stephen. The rewrite_API stuff. I will be looking into this unfortunately later. as far as yes/no, what would you say to the 3 questions. they all yes?

Comment: yes (won't be easy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the plugin [Edit Author Slug](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-author-slug/) to change the base.

Screenshot from the plugin’s settings page:

[image]

Your other question is … *another, separate* question. ;)