# Redirect Every Instance of The Author Template Pages to Custom Author Pages

Tags: customization, pages, templates, redirect, author

What I'm looking to do is actually a simple redirect, but for the EVERY page contained in the /author/ slug.  The working slug I want to redirect to is /team/.

For example, if someone were to type in: 'www.mysite.com/author/jack-sparrow', it would automatically redirect them to 'www.mysite.com/team/jack-sparrow' (the 'team' page being a page I designed with the layout editor).

I can input these redirects manually, I'm sure, but there has to be some simple succinct bit of code unbeknownst to a noobie like me that automatically redirects ALL the author template pages and tells the site to "redirect ALL /author/[firstname-lastname] to /team/[firstname-lastname]"

I would be sincerely grateful for your help!

Comment: you could just change the author base to team and remove the need to redirect.

Comment: how would this be done? do i have to change something in the php?  sorry... i'm really new with this!

Comment: the simplest method is [via a plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55569/4771).

Comment: thank you very much for that, milo.  from what i gather, though, this will merely MOVE the author template and not allow me to replace it was a custom page.  

so, if i changed the slug to 'team' for example, clicking a gravatar picture or something would merely load the author.php file into /team/~ instead of /author/~.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this with [URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).  Locate your .htaccess file and add this line above `# BEGIN WordPress`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)$ /team/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Note, if you put this inside the wordpress block it will get rewritten next time your permalinks are regenerated.

Comment: so does this mean that the /author/ template will not merely be redirected but just completely written over/erased?

by eliminating this code later, will it return to the original (for future purposes, if I wanted those pages back)?

Comment: Correct on both points.